# Can I encrypt email and decrypt it back using python default library set?

Tags: python, encryption

Of course similar questions have been asked in stackoverflow but I don't want to use any third party library like Crypto or something. So I need to generate a ciphertext from a user email and decrypt it back to plaintext. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Of course you *can* -- cryptography is nothing but math, after all, and Python can do math without extensions, so there's nothing technically stopping you from implementing any cryptorgraphy algorithm in Python -- but you shouldn't. Crypto is very hard to get right, and even folks implementing well-known algorithms often make mistakes in the implementation that compromise security.

Answer (score 5):

A third-party system is your best bet.
If you really can't/don't want to use a third-party, maybe something simple would suffice.

One of the simpler algorithms is the [Tiny Encryption Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) (TEA).  [Here's an example of a Python implementation that you could start with.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496737/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. 
Read http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto.html
You'll find an answer there ;)

You're question is not concrete enough to say more. You may want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Modern_cryptography

Cheers,
 Tuergeist

Update: 
No, you cannot. (with build in functionality due to export restrictions, see http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html)
But you can, if you're implementing you own algorithm (bad idea).
So, the BEST solution is, to use the extension recommended by python core developers. See post above.

Cheers again.

Comment: I dont want to use any third party library. PyCrypto is one such thing right!

Comment: hi tuergeist, for what reason in particular do you consider it to be a bad idea to implement your own algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is that you want to roll your own encryption system, you could try using the built-in `hmac` and `hashlib` modules.  (`hashlib` is new for 2.5, so if you must use an earlier Python, your hash choices are the older `md5` and `sha` modules.)

If you are opposed to (or are prevented from) *installing* a third-party library but are OK with using third-party algorithms or even "lightweight" third-party implementations of algorithms (e.g. published Python source code which resides in a single .py file that you can incorporate or import yourself without using `setup.py` or any other *formal* installation), then I highly recommend you do so, because these are likely to be better than what you can come up with on your own.

The smallest and user-friendliest of these that I am aware of is known as **p3**, written by cryptographer Paul Rubin.  The original link is no longer active but you can search for it.  Googling currently yields [a near-exact copy](https://github.com/zhangchunlin/gitldapacl/blob/master/p3.py) as well as [an adaptation for Python 3](https://sourceforge.net/p/treeline/devel/ci/default/tree/source/p3.py).

You could also try one of several single-module, pure-Python [Rijndael (AES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) implementations such as [this](http://fastcrypto.org/umac/2004/src/rijndael.py) or [this](http://www.bjrn.se/code/rijndaelpy.txt).  (Again, links are not guaranteed to be permanent so you may have to do some searching.)

Comment: The links are broken.