# Python encryption with only standard libs

Tags: python, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I encrypt email and decrypt it back using python default library set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806739/can-i-encrypt-email-and-decrypt-it-back-using-python-default-library-set)

I need Python to encrypt some data using a pre-set encryption key but I can't find any way to do it without installing new libs (pycrypto etc.). This is for some scripts that will be distributed to numerous devices but we can't install any new software other than this script, the only librarys we can use are the ones by default included with Python 2.4 (Specifically the build that comes with RedHat Enterprise Server 5).

The encryption needs to be secure (Secure enough to pass PCI-DSS standards for data transmission across a public network).

The clients can have full access to the encryption key, which they will have beforehand, and must be able to encrypt and decrypt data.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/806739/851737

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can fall back to calling the `openssl` executable on the system itself? This way you could pass the keys as files and data via the stdin/out and not rely on new python modules. You also get all the algorithms from openssl available directly - both symmetric and asymmetric encryption and other nice things.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a suitable pure python library, you'll have to implement one of the common algorithms yourself. Expect the pure python library to run about 100x slower than a native library